# recorrer un array hasta llegar a un numero indicado sumando cada item

Tags: php, mysql

**Tengo la siguiente Problematica:**
de un producto ingresan varios lotes en los cuales tienen precio_costo diferentes y lo que yo deseo es comparar la suma de (unidades vendidas antiguas + unidades vendidas actuales) y dar con el lote (aproximado) al cual pertenece

tengo este array:

```
array (
  '2109241713471373' => 
  array (
    0 => '2109241713471373',
    1 => '100.00',
    2 => '110',
    3 => '2|100|20.00;3|20|30.00;4|20|40.00;5|500|50.00;8|50|60.00;10|300|0.00;11|50|60.00;12|50|60.00',
  ),
  '2109241629406588' => 
  array (
    0 => '2109241629406588',
    1 => '500.00',
    2 => '1',
    3 => '1|100|10.00',
    4 => '5',
  ),
)
```

donde:
0 = id_producto
1 = precio vendido
2 = unidades a vender
3 = historial de lotes id_lote | unidades | precio_costo
4 = numero de unidades vendidas de este producto

mi logica es:

1. Recorrer cada item del array principal (`foreach`) ✓
2. Dentro del bucle con un `explode(";")` generar un array del historial de lotes ✓
3. recorrer este segundo array y dentro de este generar un array `explode("|")` de cada item para separar los datos del historial de lotes (id_lote | unidades | precio_costo)✓
4. y ahora recorrer cada historial de lotes e ir comparandolo hasta encontrar un numero que sumado con el historial anterior me de el (numero de ventas anteriores + unidades a vender)

a mi se me ocurrio esto pero estoy abierto a opiniones porfavor.
Nota:
la idea es sumar las ventas antiguas mas las unidades a vender para obtener un total de unidades por ejemplo (400)
y en base a esto ir viendo este total a que lote puede pertenecer para obtener el precio de costo

Ejemplo literal:
historial de lotes:
1 = unidades => 10  , precio_costo => 10.00
2 = unidades => 20  , precio_costo => 15.00
3 = unidades => 30  , precio_costo => 20.00
yo e vendido 13 antes y actualmente vendo 10 en total estoy vendiendo 23 unidades

entonces comparo con el primer lote de 10 unidades y me sobran
paso al siguiente lote y lo sumo mas el actual dando como resultado = 30 entonces como mis unidades vendidas es menor a la suma mi producto se encuentre actualmente vendiendo el lote #2

Lo que yo e intentado es lo siguiente:

```
foreach ($producto__in_bd as $p => $xd) {
  if($xd[3]){
  $tmp_historial = explode(";",$xd[3]);
  if($producto__in_bd[$p][4]){$total = $producto__in_bd[$p][2]+$producto__in_bd[$p][4];}else{$total = $producto__in_bd[$p][2];}

  echo $total;
  foreach ($tmp_historial as $p2 => $v2) {
    $tmp_historial_item = explode("|",$v2);
    if($tmp_historial_item[1]>=$total){
      echo "el producto <b>".$producto__in_bd[$p][0]."</b> del lote:" .$tmp_historial_item[0] . " y costo: ".$tmp_historial_item[2]."<br>";
      break;
    }else{
      
    }

  }
  }
}
```

y me retorna:

> 110el producto 2109241713471373 del lote:5 y costo: 50.00 6el producto

> 2109241629406588 del lote:1 y costo: 10.00

lo que esta haciendo es comparar los lotes hasta encontrar el que tenga mas unidades que la suma de vendidos pero esto no es lo que necesito si no ir sumando unidades de cada lote hasta que la suma me de mas que la suma de vendidos